# Error getting verification code from Microsoft with Firebase and Azure

Tags: javascript, firebase, azure, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

As a newbie to web development I'm trying to achieve the following in our Vue.js web app:

- Sign in users with their active directory credentials
- Use the Firebase Realtime Database to store data and see in the "Authentication" section in the Firebase console who logged on and when

To get this to work I followed the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth):

Install Firebase in the project and add the "Microsoft" "Sign in method" with the correct "Client ID" and "Client Secret" to the Firebase console.

Client ID:
[image]

Client secret:
[image]

Firebase console "Authentication"
[image]

In Azure App Registration we also added the "Redirect URI" as advised by Firebase:
[image]

In our project we created a "firebase.js" file:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
}


let firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');

export { firebaseApp, provider }
```

And a Vue component with only 2 buttons:

```js
<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <p>Access token: {{ OAuthAccessToken }}</p>
    <p>User details: {{ user }}</p>
    <div>
      <q-btn color="primary" @click="login"> Login </q-btn>
      <q-btn color="primary" @click="logout" class="q-ml-xl"> Logout </q-btn>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { firebaseApp, provider } from "boot/firebase";

export default {
  name: "PageHome",
  data() {
    return {
      OAuthAccessToken: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      // return 'test user'
      let test = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
      console.log("user ", test);
      return test;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      firebaseApp.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
    },
    logout() {
      firebaseApp
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(function() {
          console.log("logout succes");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("logout fail");
        });
    }
  },
  components: {},
  mounted() {
    firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential.accessToken) {
          this.OAuthAccessToken = result.credential.accessToken;
          console.log("token ", result.credential.accessToken);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("fail ", error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

When clicking the `login` button we are correctly redirected to the Microsoft sign in page, and we can sign in correctly with our AD credentials. After that we're also correctly redirected back to the app. So that part works fine. However, The following error is displayed in the console:
[image]

We tried generating a new secret in the "Azure App Registration" and use that but the issue remains. Are we missing something super obvious here?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: "consent",
  tenant: "the tenant id provided by outlook",
})
```

This will force the user to select the account to sign in has, and then enter their password. You can find the tenant [Directory (tenant) ID] the same place you got the client ID. Hope this helps, Because I legit had the same problem and found the solution by trying a couple things.

Comment: Did you maybe also got this issue: ```AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'xxx' and cannot access the application 'xxx'(xxx) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.``` Not sure why it's asking me to add that user to AD?

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: it doesn't work with tenant id

Comment: Worked for me after adding tenant id - but Had to convert SPA to web in the azure portal. (Removed SPA uri and added the same url to web)